# how to change app language inside app in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, plist

I am thinking how to update all `UILabel` having storyboard and `UITableviewController` as subview while i change language in select language page of my app not device language.

can anyone help me how can i resolved this issues

Comment: You could create a function like -(void)settingSelectedLang:(Nsstring *)selectedLang. You could call this function when user select a language and change language for all UILabel init. Also it would b a common function and can b re-used again and again. Hope I got you a solution. Let me know if anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this using Micro  Like this

open .pch file in supporting file and write down like this and one more thing you need to decide languageId first that you pass as "number"

```
#define kCancelText(number)         (number == 1 ? @"Cancel" : (number == 2 ? @"取消" : (number == 4 ? @"cancelar" :@"Cancel" )))
```

after define this you need to call like this

```
NSLog(@"Varible Print :: %@", kCancelText(1)); //Note : here 1 is language id .. I have define three language . 1. English 2. Mandarin 3. Spanish
```

You can use according to language id .. One more thing you don't need for import any this for this because its always global in app.

Comment: Hey joge..How are you?

Comment: @Sweeta, I'm fine dear and What about you?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use NSNotificationCenter through which you can post your Notification with a key, now in all the classes where you need to make changes after posting this notification, you can just add a NSNotificationObserver with the same key, from where you can call a method and do changes what so ever you require.

For using NSNotification use [this link](http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to this steps:

1>first if you have two language like arabic and English then add two .strings file
Messages_en.strings
Messages_ar.strings

// this is Messages_en.strings  file in this declare key and value
Messages_en.strings

"answer" = "Answer";

Messages_ar.strings

"answer" = "الإجابة";

2> make all label custom label like MyUILabel_custom and add all labels in all screens of this class so if you want to modify something in viewwillappear like in arabic you want to change alignment you can do in that

3> when button is clicked language should be stored in NSUserDefaults
and then you can access it everywhere

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"en" forKey:@"lang"];
```

4> In Constants.h file add this line

```
#define IsArabic ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lang"] isEqualToString:@"ar"]? YES : NO)
#define getString(key) NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, (IsArabic ? @"Messages_ar" : @"Messages_en"), @"Fix it:-(")
```

5> you can check this way in all screens viewwillappear this way 
self.lblRewardsPoint.text = getString(@"rewards_point");

6>In tableview also you can do this way you have to reload all data  and if your data came from api then you have to recall the api .

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)GetLocalString:(NSString *)text{
    NSString *path;
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentLanguageDocumentPath ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:text value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}
```

Here just add string files of languages in project and pass there file name in 'currentLanguageDocumentPath'. 
text -> key of text .